# Any alternative's for LocalBroadcastManager, like LiveData?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-livedata, localbroadcastmanager

I got a use case where I had to use Broadcast receivers in my project and came to know that the class "LocalBroadcastManager" has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/localbroadcastmanager/content/LocalBroadcastManager).

In the google docs they recommend using Livedate and I tried searching for a good example of it but I didn't see any that suits my case. Here's how I'm using broadcast receiver:

**MainActivity.java**

```
private WeekFilterStatus weekFilterStatus;

//Inside onCreate

weekFilterStatus = new WeekFilterStatus();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(weekFilterStatus, new IntentFilter("Week_filter"));

//outside onCreate
 private class WeekFilterStatus extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            txtview.SetText("Week");         
            
        }
    }
```

**Dailog.java**

```
 go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent("Week_filter");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                dismiss();
            }
        });
```

This is how I'm using in my project, I open a dialog and then hit go and the textview gets updated in main activity. And ya I have no issue with this as it is working as expected but I want to know other ways of doing exactly this with LiveData or any other methods.

If you use latest version of Android studio and try to call LocalBroadcastManager class, you may not be able to import it as that has been in my case so here is the class just in case anyone requires:

**LocalBroadcastManager.java**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2018 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects
 * within your process.  This has a number of advantages over sending
 * global broadcasts with {@link android.content.Context#sendBroadcast}:
 * <ul>
 * <li> You know that the data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so
 * don't need to worry about leaking private data.
 * <li> It is not possible for other applications to send these broadcasts to
 * your app, so you don't need to worry about having security holes they can
 * exploit.
 * <li> It is more efficient than sending a global broadcast through the
 * system.
 * </ul>
 */
public final class LocalBroadcastManager {
    private static final class ReceiverRecord {
        final IntentFilter filter;
        final BroadcastReceiver receiver;
        boolean broadcasting;
        boolean dead;

        ReceiverRecord(IntentFilter _filter, BroadcastReceiver _receiver) {
            filter = _filter;
            receiver = _receiver;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);
            builder.append("Receiver{");
            builder.append(receiver);
            builder.append(" filter=");
            builder.append(filter);
            if (dead) {
                builder.append(" DEAD");
            }
            builder.append("}");
            return builder.toString();
        }
    }

    private static final class BroadcastRecord {
        final Intent intent;
        final ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers;

        BroadcastRecord(Intent _intent, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> _receivers) {
            intent = _intent;
            receivers = _receivers;
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "LocalBroadcastManager";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private final Context mAppContext;

    private final HashMap<BroadcastReceiver, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>> mReceivers
            = new HashMap<>();
    private final HashMap<String, ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>> mActions = new HashMap<>();

    private final ArrayList<BroadcastRecord> mPendingBroadcasts = new ArrayList<>();

    static final int MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS = 1;

    private final Handler mHandler;

    private static final Object mLock = new Object();
    private static LocalBroadcastManager mInstance;

    @NonNull
    public static LocalBroadcastManager getInstance(@NonNull Context context) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new LocalBroadcastManager(context.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mInstance;
        }
    }

    private LocalBroadcastManager(Context context) {
        mAppContext = context;
        mHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()) {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS:
                        executePendingBroadcasts();
                        break;
                    default:
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Register a receive for any local broadcasts that match the given IntentFilter.
     *
     * @param receiver The BroadcastReceiver to handle the broadcast.
     * @param filter Selects the Intent broadcasts to be received.
     *
     * @see #unregisterReceiver
     */
    public void registerReceiver(@NonNull BroadcastReceiver receiver,
            @NonNull IntentFilter filter) {
        synchronized (mReceivers) {
            ReceiverRecord entry = new ReceiverRecord(filter, receiver);
            ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> filters = mReceivers.get(receiver);
            if (filters == null) {
                filters = new ArrayList<>(1);
                mReceivers.put(receiver, filters);
            }
            filters.add(entry);
            for (int i=0; i<filter.countActions(); i++) {
                String action = filter.getAction(i);
                ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> entries = mActions.get(action);
                if (entries == null) {
                    entries = new ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>(1);
                    mActions.put(action, entries);
                }
                entries.add(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Unregister a previously registered BroadcastReceiver.  <em>All</em>
     * filters that have been registered for this BroadcastReceiver will be
     * removed.
     *
     * @param receiver The BroadcastReceiver to unregister.
     *
     * @see #registerReceiver
     */
    public void unregisterReceiver(@NonNull BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
        synchronized (mReceivers) {
            final ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> filters = mReceivers.remove(receiver);
            if (filters == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i=filters.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                final ReceiverRecord filter = filters.get(i);
                filter.dead = true;
                for (int j=0; j<filter.filter.countActions(); j++) {
                    final String action = filter.filter.getAction(j);
                    final ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers = mActions.get(action);
                    if (receivers != null) {
                        for (int k=receivers.size()-1; k>=0; k--) {
                            final ReceiverRecord rec = receivers.get(k);
                            if (rec.receiver == receiver) {
                                rec.dead = true;
                                receivers.remove(k);
                            }
                        }
                        if (receivers.size() <= 0) {
                            mActions.remove(action);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Broadcast the given intent to all interested BroadcastReceivers.  This
     * call is asynchronous; it returns immediately, and you will continue
     * executing while the receivers are run.
     *
     * @param intent The Intent to broadcast; all receivers matching this
     *     Intent will receive the broadcast.
     *
     * @see #registerReceiver
     *
     * @return Returns true if the intent has been scheduled for delivery to one or more
     * broadcast receivers.  (Note tha delivery may not ultimately take place if one of those
     * receivers is unregistered before it is dispatched.)
     */
    public boolean sendBroadcast(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        synchronized (mReceivers) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            final String type = intent.resolveTypeIfNeeded(
                    mAppContext.getContentResolver());
            final Uri data = intent.getData();
            final String scheme = intent.getScheme();
            final Set<String> categories = intent.getCategories();

            final boolean debug = DEBUG ||
                    ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_DEBUG_LOG_RESOLUTION) != 0);
            if (debug) Log.v(
                    TAG, "Resolving type " + type + " scheme " + scheme
                    + " of intent " + intent);

            ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> entries = mActions.get(intent.getAction());
            if (entries != null) {
                if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "Action list: " + entries);

                ArrayList<ReceiverRecord> receivers = null;
                for (int i=0; i<entries.size(); i++) {
                    ReceiverRecord receiver = entries.get(i);
                    if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "Matching against filter " + receiver.filter);

                    if (receiver.broadcasting) {
                        if (debug) {
                            Log.v(TAG, "  Filter's target already added");
                        }
                        continue;
                    }

                    int match = receiver.filter.match(action, type, scheme, data,
                            categories, "LocalBroadcastManager");
                    if (match >= 0) {
                        if (debug) Log.v(TAG, "  Filter matched!  match=0x" +
                                Integer.toHexString(match));
                        if (receivers == null) {
                            receivers = new ArrayList<ReceiverRecord>();
                        }
                        receivers.add(receiver);
                        receiver.broadcasting = true;
                    } else {
                        if (debug) {
                            String reason;
                            switch (match) {
                                case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_ACTION: reason = "action"; break;
                                case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_CATEGORY: reason = "category"; break;
                                case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_DATA: reason = "data"; break;
                                case IntentFilter.NO_MATCH_TYPE: reason = "type"; break;
                                default: reason = "unknown reason"; break;
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, "  Filter did not match: " + reason);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (receivers != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<receivers.size(); i++) {
                        receivers.get(i).broadcasting = false;
                    }
                    mPendingBroadcasts.add(new BroadcastRecord(intent, receivers));
                    if (!mHandler.hasMessages(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS)) {
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_EXEC_PENDING_BROADCASTS);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Like {@link #sendBroadcast(Intent)}, but if there are any receivers for
     * the Intent this function will block and immediately dispatch them before
     * returning.
     */
    public void sendBroadcastSync(@NonNull Intent intent) {
        if (sendBroadcast(intent)) {
            executePendingBroadcasts();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") /* synthetic access */
    void executePendingBroadcasts() {
        while (true) {
            final BroadcastRecord[] brs;
            synchronized (mReceivers) {
                final int N = mPendingBroadcasts.size();
                if (N <= 0) {
                    return;
                }
                brs = new BroadcastRecord[N];
                mPendingBroadcasts.toArray(brs);
                mPendingBroadcasts.clear();
            }
            for (int i=0; i<brs.length; i++) {
                final BroadcastRecord br = brs[i];
                final int nbr = br.receivers.size();
                for (int j=0; j<nbr; j++) {
                    final ReceiverRecord rec = br.receivers.get(j);
                    if (!rec.dead) {
                        rec.receiver.onReceive(mAppContext, br.intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiveData by creating a ViewModel class as below

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val _text: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val text: LiveData<String> get() = _text

fun setText(newText: String) {
    _text.value = newText
}

}
```

And in MainActivity your code will be as

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_view)
    val go = findViewById<Button>(R.id.go)

    viewModel.text.observe(this) {
        textview.text = it
    }

    // todo

    go.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.setText("Week")
    }
}}
```